# Adding Text to a text box with KeyEventArgs. C#

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, keyeventargs

I can't seem to have this part of my code to work. The objective for this piece of code is to add a numbered list every time The user presses, "ENTER". Here is and example of what I mean.

0)10100[User presses the ENTER key]

1)(cursor is here)

Here is the code I have. `meowbox` is a multiline text box.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {

        meowbox.Text += i + ")";
        ++i;
    }

    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: Try meowbox.Text += "\n" + i.ToString() + ")"; The \n creates a new line before the i.ToString() method.

Comment: No good, the extra line is a typo. For some reason it wasn't formatting it right when I was asking the question. The real problem is that the i+")" won't show up in the text box.

Comment: What is the issue that you are having? Is anything happening when you press enter?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I cannot get nothing to happen when I press enter.

Comment: it looks like you're not in the KeyDown event for the text box (no `object sender` argument)

Comment: @FrancoPettigrosso I added a paragraph on how to hook up the event through the designer, that might help.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your override applies to the *form's* OnKeyDown() method, not the textbox's.  As written, it can only work when you derive your own class from TextBox.  Which is quite valid btw.  But you probably just want to use the textbox' KeyDown event instead.  You also need to think about what's going to happen when the user presses Ctrl+V to paste text.

Comment: if I use the 'object sender' arg do I have to put in an event handler on the text box then?

Comment: @RufusL I am not using the designer

Comment: Well you can hook it up through code as well, 'textbox1.KeyDown += someMethod'. The signature has to be: 'void someName(object, KeyEventArgs)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may not be putting your code in the correct method. One easy way to do it is to go to your form designer, select the textbox, go to the Properties window, click the lightning-bolt icon (for methods), and then double-click the `KeyDown` method. This will create an event handler and hook it up to the text box.

Another problem you may have (once you get it hooked up correctly) is that the textbox continues to process the key press even though you are handling it yourself. To get around this, you can set `SuppressKeyPress` to `true`.

For example:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + i++ + ") ";
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened. The problem is when I press enter, nothing happens in the text box. that is the problem I am having

Comment: Make sure you hook this method up to the KeyDown event of the textbox

Comment: @FrancoPettigrosso I added a paragraph describing how to get the event hooked up through the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! thank you guys! what i Had to do was `meowbox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler`. If you were trying to say that to me, thanks!